# Workflow For Spring Boot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, workflow

I am using spring boot-microservices version 2.7.9. I want to implement workflow in one of the services.
I have done BPMN2 workflow in a monolithic application. Can anyone suggest a lightweight and easy-to-implement workflow for the microservice?

I have used BPMN2 workflow in a monolithic application.

Answer (score 0):

We are using Camunda workflow engine for our spring boot based microservices. They have proper documentation and so far, we didn't face much issue. You can check here for more information. Camunda Spring boot Link: https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring-boot/